# Swiftui User Multiple Selection To Array of Object

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have the following response from API

```
"features": [
        {
            "name": "Safety",
            "_id": "636a638959d10a2603b8d645",
            "values": [
                    Array of String
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Entertainment",
            "_id": "636a64312bbe0cd292a1ffc6",
            "values": [
                Array of String
            ]
```

Which I decode it with :

```
struct Feature : Codable , Hashable{
    var name : String = ""
    var values : [Value] = []
}

struct Value : Codable, Hashable{
    var value : String = ""
    var unit : String = ""
}
```

And in the view is render it like :

```
var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Choose Your Features").font(Font.body.bold())
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.leading, 15)
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
                VStack{
                    
                    ForEach(Array(features.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { featureIndex, feature in
                        HStack{
                            Text(feature.name).font(Font.body.bold())
                            Spacer()
                        }.padding(.bottom , 10)
                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                            HStack(spacing : 10){
                                ForEach(Array(feature.values.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { valueIndex, value in
                                    
                                    FeatureCell(isSelected: $isSelected, value: value).onTapGesture{
                                        // here
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }
                            Divider().padding(10)
                        }
                    }.padding(15)
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

The user may select multiple item from each feature values list, Now Im really confused  about how to store these selections in an array of features object again, I tried almost every thing like Array, Set and Dictionaries but could not reach any solution.

**Update :**  This is the json object I should send back

```
   {
    "features": [
        {
            "Safety": [
                "value1",
                "value9",
                "value3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Entertainment": [
                "value7",
                "value2",
                "value8"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help or ideas will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You usually want to use a `Set` to store which items are selected. This set should be a `State` variable instantiated in the parent view. The `onTapGesture` closure will add or remove the value to the set. If the `FeatureCell` needs to know whether the value is selected, simply use the `.contains` method.

```
struct FeatureValueSelectionView: View {
    // The feature whose values we are displaying
    let feature: Feature

    // Note: You may have to manually conform Value to the Hashable protocol
    @State private var selectedValues = Set<Value>()

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(feature.values) { value in
            FeatureCell(selected: selectedValues.contains(value), value: value)
                .onTapGesture { selectedValues.toggle(value) }
        }
    }
}
```

For toggling a value in a set, I like to use this simple extension:

```
extension Set {
    public mutating func toggle(_ element: Element) {
        if self.contains(element) {
            self.subtract([element])
        } else {
            self.insert(element)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still didn't figure out how to get the final array of features ? assume that there is a next button in my view that should send the selected features array to the backend

Comment: The `selectedValues` set contains the features that the user has selected. So passing those as a parameter to the next view should suffice. You can turn the property from a `Set<Value>` to an array `[Value]` like this if you need to: `selectedValues.map { $0 }`

Comment: I think i miss understood you, how can i reference the `Set<Value>` to its feature name, please can you check the update ip post on the question